# Multiple definitions when making kernel module over multiple source files

Tags: c, linker, makefile, kernel-module

I think the problem is having **one** header file that has **all** items that my source files needs, but how do I fix this? Is it possible to use one or must I split them up with their own includes functionalities.

I not sure what wrong with my `.h` file that I'm including in all my source files. I read that the problem is each source file is compiling separately with this `.h` file and when linking all source files together, the compile finds there are multiple definitions even though I have a include guard.

How can I go about this? There's `prototype.h` that includes all my **function prototypes**, **includes**, **extern** variables, and **structs**. I have a few source files that all need some portion of this `.h` file.

My make file is as follows

```
TARGET = betty

obj-m := $(TARGET).o

betty-objs := main.o helpers.o syscall_overrides.o

KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(RM) .*.cmd *.o *.ko -r .tmp*
```

And the error message (a portion of them) that it gives is:

```
/home/admin/Dropbox/COMP3000/FinalModule/helpers.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `clean_sys_mkdir'
/home/admin/Dropbox/COMP3000/FinalModule/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/home/admin/Dropbox/COMP3000/FinalModule/helpers.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `clean_sys_execve'
/home/admin/Dropbox/COMP3000/FinalModule/main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
/home/admin/Dropbox/COMP3000/FinalModule/helpers.o:(.bss+0xc): multiple definition of `clean_getdents64_syscall'
```

Code:

main.c

```
#define MODULE_NAME "Betty"

#include "prototypes.h"

extern unsigned long **syscall_table;

static int __init init(void)
{
    ...
}

static void __exit shutdown(void)
{
   ...
}

module_init(init);
module_exit(shutdown);

MODULE_LICENSE("..");
MODULE_AUTHOR("..");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("..");
```

prototype.h

```
#ifndef PROTOTYPE_H
#define PROTOTYPE_H

#include <linux/module.h>    // mandatory kernel module 
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // __init and __exit
#include <asm/unistd.h>      // __NR syscall nums
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/tty.h>       // tty_struct
#include <linux/tty_driver.h>// write (already included by tty.h)
#include <linux/sched.h>     // current
#include <linux/random.h>    // get_random_bytes
#include <linux/syscalls.h>  // from sys_execve asmlinkage 
#include <linux/dirent.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>      // kmalloc()
#include <linux/time.h>      // time
#include <linux/rtc.h>             // rtc_time_to_tm

/*
  Function prototypes for both original and custom syscalls that Betty uses
*/
asmlinkage long (*clean_sys_mkdir)(const char __user *pathname, umode_t mode);
asmlinkage long (*clean_sys_execve)(const char __user *filename,
                const char __user *const __user *argv,
                const char __user *const __user *envp);
asmlinkage long (*clean_getdents64_syscall) (unsigned int fd,
            struct linux_dirent64 __user * dirent,
            unsigned int count);

static void find_process_id_to_hide(char* process_nm);

extern unsigned long **syscall_table;


#endif
```

helpers.c

```
#include "prototypes.h"

extern unsigned long **syscall_table; // extern variable 

... just functions in this one defined in prototype.h
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @kaylum I have updated it with a portion to restrict the size. Do you think this error could be from code?

Comment: OKAY, I understand why you asked me. Every source file that includes should have an include guard, which I missed in my source files. Now the problem becomes, how does my other source files get access to task variables like `current` or... `NULL`, they seems to be undeclared in my other source files. Seems like my other source files need `prototype.h` in order to compile

Comment: If some source file needs things, *directrly* declared in `prototype.h`, then it could include this header. If the source file needs only things, defined in "system" header(like `current`), it could include corresponded header directly: `#include <linux/sched.h>`. But including whole `prototype.h` is also OK. BTW, you code uses -- include "prototype**s**.h" --, but other text in you post referres to it as `prototype.h`. What is actual name of the file?